# How to remove Item for the dictonary of <string, list<Items>>

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, c#-4.0

I have a dictionary of fruits `<string, list<Fruit>>` My dictionary is giving below output

```
Job ID: 1001         items:
                        "Apple"
                        "Mango"
                        "Banana"
                        "Pine Apple"
                        "Orange"

Job ID: 1002         items:
                        "Banana"
                        "Mango"
                        "Pine Apple"
                        "Orange"
                        "Apple"

Job ID: 1003         items:
                        "Apple"
                        "Banana"
                        "Orange"
                        "Pine Apple"
                        "Mango"
```

Now I want to remove a specific fruit from the list of fruit

for example, I want to remove `Apple` from the list

```
foreach(var i in fruitDic)
            {
                foreach(var k in i.Value)
                {
                    // furitName is variable which I want to remove from list
                    if (k.Name == fruitName)
                    {
                        // here I am getting an error
                        k.Value.Remove(fruitName);

                    }
                }
            }
```

I am getting an error saying: `Error  CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'Practice.Models.Fruit'`

Comment: Note your question is a little ordinary. The data is not a useful representation of `<string, list<Fruit>>` and as such a little confusing, which is the only reasons why this wasn't answered sooner I am guessing

Comment: @saghar francis: Does the `List<Fruit>` has duplicated items? If not, then use [`SortedSet<Fruit>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedset-1?view=netframework-4.8) instead: will give more performance.

Comment: @saghar In the line `if (k.Name == fruitName)` k is an item from the list of string, so it will be `if (k == fruitName)`, by the way in a `foreach` loop you cannot modify the collection i.e. remove any item, you can just modify any property of the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`RemoveAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeall?view=net-5.0)

> Removes all the elements that match the conditions defined by the
> specified predicate.

**Given**

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, List<Fruit>>();
```

**Usage**

```
foreach (var list in dict.Values)
   list.RemoveAll(x => x.Name == "SomeFunkyFruit");
```